# Content disappears after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a blog app that is divided into two parts. The first part is where people can write the actual blog (title, short description, body, click on the submit button) and that blog is than displayed to the screen with all the other blogs. These blogs are clickable and can be viewed. This part works just fine. If people click on a blog they can write comments to it. It works similarly like the part where you can write the blogs (people write a comment, click on the submit button and it is displayed below the blog post). Everything is store in firebase. The problem is when I refresh the page in the comment section, everything disappears and I get no error message. If I don't refresh the comment section everything works perfect, but after refresh everything disappears, but no error message is shown.

Here are the components for the comment section:
CommentHolder is responsible for displaying the comments that are connected with the actual blog post

```
import React from 'react';
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';
import DeleteComment from './DeleteComment'

class CommentHolder extends React.Component {
    state = { docs: [] }
    _isMounted = false;

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const fetchDataFromFireBase = async () => {
            const getData = await projectFirestore.collection("Comments")
            getData.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                var documents = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                });
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ docs: documents })
                }
            });
        }
        fetchDataFromFireBase()
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    renderContent() {

        // Delete comments
        const deleteComment = async (id) => {
            projectFirestore.collection('Comments').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
                console.log(`Blog with id: ${id} has been successfully deleted!`)
            })
        }

        // Build comments
        let user;
        if (localStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            user = [];
        } else {
            user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

            const commentArray = this.state.docs?.filter(value => value.blogID === this.props.param);
            const orderedComments = commentArray.sort((a, b) => (a.time > b.time) ? -1 : (b.time > a.time) ? 1 : 0);
            const renderComments = orderedComments.map(comment => {
                return (
                    <div key={comment.id} className="card mb-3" >
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm">
                                    <h6>{`${comment.name} - ${comment.time}`}</h6>
                                    <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-sm text-right">
                                    {user[0].id === comment.userID ? <DeleteComment commentid={comment.id} onDeleteComment={deleteComment} /> : ''}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })

            const updateComments = () => {
                const queryString = window.location.search;
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
                const id = urlParams.get('id')

                const updateComment = projectFirestore.collection('Blogs').doc(id);
                return updateComment.update({
                    'post.comments': commentArray.length
                })
            }
            updateComments()
            return renderComments;

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentHolder
```

The AddComment contains the whole section, the text area, the submit button and the container for the comments

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import SubmitComment from './SubmitComment'
import CommentHolder from './CommentHolder';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const AddComment = ({ param }) => {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const state = useSelector((state) => state.state);

    if(state) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setComment('')
            dispatch({ type: "SET_FALSE" })
        }, 50)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <div className="form-group">
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Comment" className="form-control mb-3" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
            <SubmitComment comment={comment} param={param} />
            </div>
            <CommentHolder param={param} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddComment
```

The SubmitComment is responsible for submitting the comment to the firebase

```
import React from 'react'
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const SubmitComment = ({ comment, param }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onCommentSubmit = () => {
        let user;
        if (localStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            user = [];
        } else {
            user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            projectFirestore.collection('Comments').doc().set({
                id: uuidv4(),
                comment,
                name: `${user[0].firstName} ${user[0].lastName}`,
                userID: user[0].id,
                blogID: param,
                time: new Date().toLocaleString()
            })

            dispatch({ type: "SET_TRUE" });
        }
    }

    

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onCommentSubmit()} className='btn btn-primary'>Add comment</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SubmitComment
```

The DeleteComment just deletes the comment

```
import React from 'react'

const DeleteComment = ({ commentid, onDeleteComment }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onDeleteComment(commentid)} className='btn btn-outline-danger'>X</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DeleteComment
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: did you check if comments are really saved in firebase database after adding a new one?

Comment: const state = useSelector((state) => state.state); ? would be really helpful if you can share initialState after getting data and check if data is created in firebase!

Comment: Yes, they are saved in firebase. When I refresh the page not only the comments disappear but the text area, the submit button and the whole blog post as well. That state variable is Redux that helps clear the input field after submitting the comment. It does not affect anything. The disappearance started way before I used Redux.